# How to stop Dropbox from syncing certain folders on certain Os?

Tags: dropbox

I have Dropbox on my phone, my Debian Os and my Windows 7. I put all my projects on Dropbox,  for example, my django and my corona sdk projects are on dropbox.

I don't want my corona sdk projects to be synced to my phone nor my Linux because I only do my corona projects on windows, I don't want to waste bandwidth nor disk space by downloading files on my phone, same story about django, I only do django on Linux, why would i need my django projects on my phone?!

Is there a way to specify what folder to be synced on each OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to specify which folders you want to sync in your dropbox preferences. I don't know how to do it on your phone, but on windows, I usually right click, click the little gear, then pick Preferences, go to tab Advanced and click the button <kbd>Selective Sync...</kbd> From there, I pick the folders I want to sync.

These will apply only to this machine. You can then change the settings on your phone, and other OS.

Comment: unfortunately this option isn't available on mobile version

Comment: @Fischer Aw.. okay, I hope you can find some workaround or something.

Answer (score 2):

Create two Dropbox accounts, one is used for phone sign-in and the other is used for Windows sign-in. Then from your Windows Dropbox to share whatever the folders you want to be used on phone. This is not a perfect solution but at least you can choose which folder to show up on your phone.

Comment: This is genius. I'll be creating a second account, but that second account won't own any of it's folders. It'll only have folders shared from my first account. That way I can select which folders sync from the cloud, rather than the device.